# Proof Using Mathematical Induction that $2^n \geq n + 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction

$2^n \geq  n + 1$, for all $n \geq  1$

So I know that first I should use 1, which I did to make sure step 1 holds.
$$2 ^ 1 \geq 1 + 1\\2 \geq 2\\ \mathsf{TRUE}$$

After I figure this out, I know I am then supposed to assume it true for $k$, so I get $2 ^ k \geq k + 1$, but its the whole $k+1$ step that completely looses me. Where would I do from here? I am assuming that I have to get $2 ^ k \geq k + 1$ to equal   $2 ^{k+1} \geq k+1 + 1$, but am not sure how to get there.

Comment: You say "*have to get* $2^k\geq k+1$ **to equal** $2^{k+1}\geq k+1+1$"  The phrase "*to equal*" should instead be replaced with "*to* **imply**"

Comment: You need to ASSUME $2^k \ge k+1$ and from *that* you have to SHOW that that means $2^{k+1} \ge (k+1) + 1$.  It can go like this $2^{k+1} = 2^k*2 = 2^k + 2^k \ge (k+1) + (k+ 1) \ge (k+1) + 1$ and .... well that would be it.

Answer (score 2):

You want to show that $2^{k+1}\geq(k+1)+1$ using the induction hypothesis. This hypothesis concerns $2^k$, so you will want to make this term appear from $2^{k+1}$. Just remark that $2^{k+1}=2\cdot2^{k}$. Hence, using the induction hypothesis, you can infer
$$
2^{k+1}=2\cdot2^{k}\geq2\cdot(k+1)=2k+2\geq k+2=(k+1)+1
$$
which is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

$2^{k+1}=2^k\cdot 2=2^k+2^k\ge(k+1)+1=k+2$ by using induction hypothesis $2^k\ge k+1$ and $2^k\ge 1$

Answer (score 0):

You are off to a great start.

So, assuming that $2^k\geq k+1$ then: $$\begin{align}&\quad 2^{k+1} \\[1ex]&= 2(2^k) \\[1ex]&\geq 2(k+1) \tag 1 \\[1ex]&= (k+1)+(k+1)\\[1ex]&\geq (k+1)+1 \tag 2\end{align}$$

Can you justify these steps?

Then you have that $\forall k\geq 1: \Big(\big(2^k\geq k+1\big) ~\implies~\big(2^{k+1}\geq (k+1)+1\big)\Big)$ and $2^1\geq 1+1$ so...

Comment: It makes sense except for when you go from 2(2^k) to 2(k + 1). I'm not following that step.

Comment: @Steberz *Assuming* that $2^k\geq k+1$ then $2(2^k)\geq 2(k+1)$

Comment: Okay, that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM inequality $\frac{2^n+(n-1)}{n}=\frac{2^n+1+1+...+1}{n}\ge \sqrt[n]{2^n}=2\implies 2^n \ge 2n-(n-1)=n+1$